# Confusion in propositional logic

Tags: logic

How do I prove this Propositional Logic? 
T → (E ∨ ¬ L) 
(E → M) ∧ (¬ L → K)    
/∴ T → (M ∨ K)

This is my proof process, I have been thinking about it for a long time, and it feels like I'm almost there.

1. (T)→((E)∨(¬(L)))         => premise
2. ((E)→(M))∧((¬(L))→(K))   => premise
3. (E)→(M)                  => 2,2, Simp
4. ((¬(L))→(K))∧((E)→(M))   => 2, Comm
5. (¬(L))→(K)                =>    4,4, Simp
6. (T)→((¬(L))∨(E))        =>  1, Comm
7. (T)→((L)→(E))          =>   6, Impl
8. ((T)∧(L))→(E)          =>   7, Exp
9. ((T)∧(L))→(M)           =>  8,3, HS
10. (T)→((L)→(M))            =>   9, Exp#

Many thanks in advance.